# Need new eyes on a mysql query statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new at this, what are the problems with this statement:

```
$sql=" SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `DayId` ='".$day."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);


if (!$result){
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {             //set $dayType
    $dayType = $row[DayType];       
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
DB Error, could not query the database 
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

but when I put an "echo $result;" in after the line that starts with $result=... then I get a value for $result of "Resource id #2"

Comment: var_dump($day) please; I think it is empty

Comment: What is in `$day`? What does `$sql` contain after the assignment? Also, building a SQL statement this way is how SQL Injection occurs.  This is a very bad way to code this; use `?` placeholders instead.

Comment: $day = date(z); so it's value is 195

Comment: @JEGM: Not sufficient.  You must display the value of `$sql` to debug this.

Comment: ok, give me a minute and I'll get it posted

Comment: $sql is "SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `DayId` =196"

Comment: $conn= Resource id #1 if it helps

Comment: yes that is ... you need a quote around 196 like '196'. So was the error

Comment: quotes around 196 didn't make a difference

Comment: I'm still not sure why it made a difference, but $sql = "SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `DayId` = " . $day.""; works

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your "day" variable in quotes (and you should be escaping it if you haven't already!)

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE DayId = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($day) . "'";`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `DayId` = '".$day."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely to me that your $day variable is not getting populated ... Try echoing the SQL statement before you run it to make sure everything looks as it should ...

Answer (score 0):

If it's date(z) change it to date('z').

Comment: added that as well, but it wasn't the problem.